# Select rows up to and including the last row with the first value in a column

Tags: sql, oracle

Given a result set like this, ordered by `AccountId`:

```
| AccountId | Foo | Bar | ... |
| 7981      | x   |  12 | ... |
| 7981      | y   |  23 | ... |
| 7981      | z   |   8 | ... |
| 7981      | q   | 142 | ... |
| 64734     | x   |  31 | ... |
| 64734     | q   |  12 | ... |
```

I want to select **all rows** with **all columns** for the first `AccountId`, regardless of the actual value of `AccountId` and regardless of the number of rows.
(In other words, select all rows until the value in the first column changes.)

To get this result set takes a lot of joins and clauses, so using something like `group by` and a limit to get the first `AccountId` in a sub query is not the type of solution I am looking for. Because I will have to duplicate a lot of code.

I have been experimenting with `... over (partition by AccountId)` functions. But they all seem to operate on the values inside the partitions created by the `partition by`.

One solution I envision is a function that assigns the number 1 to all rows in the first `partition by AccountId` partition, and the number 2 to all rows in the second partition, etc. Then I can just add `where group = 1`.

Comment: Which column defines what the "first" `AccountId` actually is?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I'm not sure what you mean. The first value in the `AccountId` column.

Comment: Oracle SQL tables don't really have any "order."  The data you are showing us also is not ordered, and the "first" value is just what happens to be there.

Comment: Which Oracle version are you using?

Comment: Please show your query's `ORDER BY` clause that leads to one account being shown first.

Comment: The result set is ordered by `AccountId`

Answer (score 1):

How about selecting the minimum AccountId in a subquery and then showing all rows with this AccountId?

The code would be something like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM accounts
WHERE AccountId IN (
  SELECT MIN(AccountId)
  FROM accounts
)
```

EDIT:
Since you said it is a quite long query, then you could make it a little faster by using EXISTS instead of IN operator:

```
SELECT * 
FROM accounts accsMain
WHERE EXISTS(
  SELECT MIN(AccountId)
  FROM accounts accsSub
  WHERE accsMain.AccountId = accsSub.AccountId
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but like I said in the question, a solution based on a sub query is not ideal because it will result in lots of duplicate code between the main query and the sub query.

Answer (score 1):

The following query return the first AccountId with all other row data for that account. The query below is more optimized than other solution.

Update: I used multiple CTE to solve the problem. In the update, your query used only once.

```
with
    [query_result]
as
(
    select
        AccountId   ,
        Foo         ,
        Bar
    from
        [Your_Table]
),
    first_account
as
(
    select
        AccountId,
        row_number() over(order by AccountId) as RowNum
    from
        [query_result]
)
select
    r.AccountId ,
    r.Foo       ,
    r.Bar
from
    [query_result]  as r
inner join
    first_account   as fa
on
    r.AccountId = fa.AccountId
where
    fa.RowNum = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks. however, in my case there is not realy a `[Your_Table]` since the result set I'm showing is the result of a query. And I don't want to repeat that query multiple times.

Comment: @MichielvanOosterhout I updated the answer and your query does't repeat multiple times. you need to replace [Your_Table] with your query.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to reference the table once, you can use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, min(accountid) over () as min_accountid
      from t
     ) t
where min_accountid = accountid;
```

or `rank()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (order by accountid) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

This is helpful if `t` is a complex query or view.

Comment: Thanks, I like the idea of selecting `where min_accountid = accountid`, that's the kind of 'thinking in SQL' that I would not have come up with myself.

Answer (score 0):

one way to avoid the duplicate code is to use the `WITH` Clause

```
with complex_query AS
(
  SELECT AccountId, foo, bar, ...
  ... complex stuff here
)
SELECT *
FROM complex_query 
WHERE 
  AccountId = ( SELECT MIN(AccountId) FROM complex_query) 
;
```

If you prefer the analytic functions, you kann use them without specifying the Partition part, like this

```
SELECT  MIN(AccountId) OVER() AS minAccountId, AccountId ...
```

then they operate on the entire result set

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure i'm understand you case. 
You can with analytic function.

```
 select * from (   
   select first_value(AccountId) over() my_first_AccountId, complex_query.*
    from 
    ( select AccountId ,... from t1,t2..,tn order by t1.x,t2.y,t3.z>  ) complex_query
     )
  where my_first_AccountId = AccountId
```

Working example

```
 select * from (

 select first_value(table_name) over() my_first_value, complex_query.*
  from 
   ( select * from user_tab_cols order by table_name ) complex_query
  )
  where my_first_value = table_name
```